# How does List<T>.IndexOf() search?

Tags: c#

Haven't found a definite answer on this so I'm going to ask it here. Sorry if I missed something.

Say we have this class

```cs
internal class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }
    private string my_field;
    public string MyField
    { 
        get { return my_field; }
        set { my_field = value; }
    }
}
```

and we create a `List<MyClass>` like this and populate it with testing info

```cs
List<MyClass> my_list = new List<MyClass>();
private void TestFunction()
{
     MyClass mc = new MyClass();
     mc.my_field = "test1";
     my_list.Add(mc);
}
```

My question is, will `IndexOf()` return the real index of `mc` if I create an identical `MyClass` object with the same `my_field` value? If not, why ?

```cs
private void SearchList()
{
     MyClass mc = new MyClass();
     mc.my_field = "test1";
     int index = my_list.IndexOf() // WILL THIS RETURN THE INDEX OF THE PREVIOUSLY ADDED "mc" OBJECT
}
```

Comment: You could simply try, much faster than asking. The answer is no -- and to figure out why, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof) will be helpful (the remarks tell you how `.IndexOf` searches).

Comment: `IndexOf` uses `System.Collection.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.Default`

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646 -> line 638

Comment: I did actually test it after posting, expected it to not work but was really curious why.

Comment: The default comparison for class objects is by reference and you have two object references. You can change the way comparing works by overriding the `Equals` method in the class or by specifying another `IEqualityComparer<T>` when searching.

Comment: I will close the question. Thanks for the helpful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this here as it may help someone somewhere.
Thanks to the comments I understood how `IndexOf()` works.
Basically the method uses the `Equals()` method to find the matching object and return the index of the provided object.

Here is the relevant documentation from msdn
[List.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-6.0)